# Let $X$ be such that $S=e^x$. You are given that $M_X(u)=e^{5u+2u^2}$

Tags: probability

Suppose, for the stock market, the price of a certain stock S has density function $f_S(s)=\frac{1}{ts\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(s)-m}{i}\right)^2}$ where $S>0$  and $-\infty<m<\infty $ and $t>0$ are constants.

Let $X$ be such that $S=e^x$. You are given that $M_X(u)=e^{5u+2u^2}$.

Given that $S$ is greater than $50$, what is the probability that is between $70$ and $90$?

I know if $M_X(u)=e^{5u+2u^2}$ then  $X$ is a normal distribution with parameters $\mu= 5 $ and $\sigma^2= 4 $ now I don´t kwon that I should do

Thanks for yours help have a nice day :)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, but: If you've got the density function, can't you just integrate from 50 to inf, and from 70 to 90 to get the answer?

Comment: @Mars           No, It´s more complicated than that, because this integral is practically "impossible" to solve  manually

Comment: Ah, OK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told that $X\gt \ln(50)$, and want to find the probability that $\ln(70)\lt X\lt \ln(90)$.

Let $A$ be the event $\ln(70)\lt X\lt \ln(90)$, and $B$ the event $X\gt \ln(50)$. We want $\Pr(A|B)$.

This is $\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Note that in our case we have $A\cap B=A$. So we need to find $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$.

These are standard normal distribution calculations.